# Find limits as $n \to \infty$ (a) $x_n=(3\sqrt{n})^{1/2n}$ (b) $y_n=(n+1)^{1/ln(1+n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Determine the limits of the two sequences as $n  \to \infty$

(a) $x_n=(3\sqrt{n})^{1/2n}$

(b) $y_n=(n+1)^{1/\ln(1+n)}$

For (a) I tried:

$\lim[(3\sqrt{n})^{1/2n}] = \lim[(3^{1/n})^{1/2}\cdot(n^{1/n})^{1/4}]$

$\lim(3^{1/n}) = 1$ and so $\lim[(3^{1/n})^{1/2}] = 1^{1/2} = 1   $

also $\lim(n^{1/n}) = 1$ and so $ \lim[(n^{1/n})^{1/4}] = 1^{1/4}  $

so $\lim[(3^{1/n})^{1/2}\cdot(n^{1/n})^{1/4}] = 1\cdot1 = 1$

Comment: $1$ is the correct answer for a)

Comment: prove that for b) we get $e$ as the limes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a). Is correct (both the result and your proof -- assuming, of course, you can use the fact that $n^{\frac{1}{n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1$).

For b): using that $a^b = e^{b\ln a}$ (for $a>0$), you can rewrite
$$
(n+1)^{\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}}
= \exp\left(\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\ln(n+1)\right)=
e^1 \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} ? 
$$